# Oracle APEX How to submit page with PL/SQL insert/update and then transition to next page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX page that collects data via a classic report with apex_item dynamically generated items. Something like this:

```
select apex_item.radiogroup(qt.save_position, 1, qt.answer, null, null, null, null) col01
from   xxpay_360_questions qt
where  qt.questionnaire_id = 21
```

I then save the answers using a submit button that uses "Submit Page" and calls PL/SQL to insert/update the dynamically generated items from above. Something like this:

```
insert into xxpay_360_answers values (apex_application.g_user, APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(1));    
commit;
```

My question is how can I also do a transition to the next page of dynamically generated items (since I only have 50 apex variables to play with per page) when the submit button is clicked.

The submit button only has options for "Submit Page" and "Transition to Page" and not "Submit Page and then Transition to Page".

Is there a way of transitioning via PL/SQL as part of the submit code? Or is there an event that can transition after the page has been submitted?

Also how does this work with errors and the nice "Saved" fly over that apex has?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a Branch, on the after processing region:

[image]

Then you need to set as branch point: **On Submit After Processing (After Computation, Validation and Processing)** and the branch type as: **Branch to page**

[image]

Then specify the page number where your going to:

[image]

And finally you can set the branch to be fired only if one particular button is pressed and if one particular condition evaluates to true:

[image]

I think that would cover your needs.

But if you want to do it with PL/SQL you could do something like this:

Replace the page ID with the actual page Id to which you want to redirect the user.

```
BEGIN

  IF(CONDITION)THEN

    htp.init;

    owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:10:&APP_SESSION.'); /*Replace 10 with actual Page Number*/

    apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

  ELSE

    htp.init;

    owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:20:&APP_SESSION.'); /*Replace 20 with actual Page Number*/

    apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

  END IF;

END;
```

Or you could use the [APEX_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_util.htm#AEAPI2324) procedure.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using APEX 4.2 refer the APEX_UTIL reference from [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_util.htm#AEAPI2324)

You can use:

```
apex_util.redirect_url(
 p_url => 'type your url here' 
);
```

This effectively calls in the owa_util. redirect_url and automatically calls apex_application.stop_apex_engine.

Comment: Is there a way to -not- call stop engine automatically?